# HP Server LTO-6 Ultrium 6250 high sound fan some times

Tags: windows, hp, fan

**Dear Sir,**
We have server HP Server LTO-6 Ultrium 6250
its give some times high speed and sound fan, some times sound disappear
where temperature at server room 17 degree its cool we have windows server 2008
appreciate your support